# How do I remove the small space above the VML shape I put inside an html table cell?

Tags: css, xml, vml

I'm attempting to put right triangles in table cells using VML for Outlook that will extend from the bottom of the cell to the top. However, for some reason, a small gap appears above the shape inside the cell. I'd like to remove this space. The space above the shape can be seen below:

[image: Image of VML Shape issue]

Here's the code for one of the cells with a right triangle inside:

**CSS**

```css
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0;
  mso-line-height-rule: exactly; 
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

**VML**

```
<td style="background-color: #ffffff" width="20px">                                                             
  <div style="background-color: #ffe01a; mso-hide:all;">                                                             
    <div style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 0; height: 0;
                border-style: solid; border-width: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
                border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent; mso-hide:all;">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--[if mso]>
  <v:shape filled="true" style="width:20px; height:20px; mso-position-horizontal:left; mso-position-vertical:top;"
           fillcolor="#ffe01a" stroked="f" path="M 1000,0 L 0,1000, X E" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
  <o:lock selection="t"/><v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
  <!--[if mso]></v:textbox></v:shape><![endif]-->
</td>
```